# Run multiple Javascript async calls in parallel without using self-executing functions (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, iife

My code has to call a few web services. To speed that up, I want to do that in parallel. However, the results of those services must be executed *before* `Promise.all()` resolves. Here's my current code:

```js
const awaitors = [];

if (!targetLocation) {
    awaitors.push((async function () {
        targetLocation = await getStorageLocation(storageID);
    })());
}

if (!carrierToMove) {
    awaitors.push(/* Another similar call that sets carrierToMove */);
}

await Promise.all(awaitors);
pushCarrierIntoStorage(carrierToMove, targetLocation);
```

As you can see, I'm using a self-executing javascript function there. That doesn't really contribute to the readability of my code. Is there a better way to implement that without losing the ability to execute both calls in parallel?

Comment: "*the results of those services must be executed before `Promise.all()` resolves.*" - why? You're not using them before.

Answer (score 0):

In general, aim achieve this type of thing by returning values instead of depending on side effects (i.e. assigning values to variables in the wider scope).

```
const promiseTargetLocation = getStorageLocation(storageID);
const promiseCarrierToMove = anotherSimilarCall();
const [carrierToMove, targetLocation] = await Promise.all([promiseCarrierToMove, promiseTargetLocation];
pushCarrierIntoStorage(carrierToMove, targetLocation);
```

or, more concisely:

```
pushCarrierIntoStorage(...(await Promise.all([anotherSimilarCall(), getStorageLocation(storageID)])));
```

Comment: The problem in my application is, that both variables *could* already be defined by previous code.

Comment: Then test for that before making the request for a replacement. e.g. `const promiseTargetLocation = existingLocation ?? getStorageLocation(storageID);`

Comment: Or make `getStorageLocation` responsible for immediately returning the existing data instead of getting new data.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because `getStorageLocation` is an API method and I am not allowed to modify it.

Comment: You can wrap it in your own function (or use my previous suggestion)

Comment: I see where you aim towards, but in my case, this would introduce additional overhead. Both variables are getting defined in a part of the code. So, my only option would be to do something like `const newTargetLocationAwaitor = async () => targetLocation || await getTargetLocation();`. This would introduce overhead and ballast.

Comment: You've already got that overhead with `if (!targetLocation) {`. This moves it and makes the code more straightforward in the process.

Comment: I think that initializing a thread executing an async function is much more costly than a simple branch, isn't it?

Comment: @AndréReichelt — It's completely insignificant compared to the expense of making a network request. [Don't optimise things that aren't your bottlenecks](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: The question is, if I really gain something by replacing a non-ideal approach with another non-ideal approach. Do you think so in this particular case?

Comment: @AndréReichelt — I can't run performance metrics on your code base. Putting multiple network requests in parallel has a reasonable chance of having an impactiful and positive effect on performance. Avoiding extra function calls is very unlikely to have significant effect in performance. Optimising for readability is very likely to have a positive effect on development / maintenance / debugging effort.

Comment: @AndréReichelt Executing an `async` function does not initialise a thread. It's a normal function with extra syntactic sugar for creating promises. No multithreading involved anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pity that the main purpose of the IIFE is a *side-effect*, which I would find the principle disadvantage of that pattern.

Instead you could do this:

```
const carrierAndStorage = await Promise.all([
    carrierToMove ?? getCarrier(someID),
    targetLocation ?? getStorageLocation(storageID)
]);

pushCarrierIntoStorage(...carrierAndStorage);
```

The `??` operator replaces your `if`.

As you can see, it is OK to include `carrierToMove` in the array that `Promise.all` gets, even when it is already non-nullish. In that case it will be converted to a promise that resolves immediately to that value.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const awaitors = [];

if (!targetLocation) {
    awaitors.push(getStorageLocation(storageID).then(targetLocation => {
        // process targetLocation 
    }));
}

if (!carrierToMove) {
    awaitors.push(/* do the same as above */);
}

// by the time this resolves, individual
// requests will be processed:
await Promise.all(awaitors); 

pushCarrierIntoStorage(carrierToMove, targetLocation);
```